# @Html.DropDownList set id dynamically in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I need to set dynamically the id of a @Html.DropDownList

This is a piece of my MVC view

```
@{
    row_number = 0;

    }
.....
@foreach (var item in Model)
   {
.....
<div style="float:left;width:100px">
          @Html.DropDownList("ID_", new SelectList(ViewBag.LISTA_LINEE, "Value", "Text"),string.Empty)
        </div>
........
      row_number = row_number + 1;

       }
```

I need to add

```
row_number
```

value to drop down list ID dinamically.

What is the correct sintax?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number` is an integer, and `"ID_"` is a string.  MVC Razor or otherwise, it's still just C# code.  You can build a string from those values like this:

```
string.Format("ID_{0}", row_number)
```

So the whole thing would be:

```
@Html.DropDownList(string.Format("ID_{0}", row_number), new SelectList(ViewBag.LISTA_LINEE, "Value", "Text"),string.Empty)
```